# why is alert box popping out even if I input correct amount of strings/data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there something wrong with my validation for the username var ?, i don't know why the alert box keeps popping out even if i provided the correct data for username:(

```
 if(userid == ""){
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 230,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Register": function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $('div#registerpopup').dialog({
                   resizable: false,
                   height: 485,
                   width: 420,
                   modal: true,
                   buttons: {
                        "Register": function(){
                          if(username == "" || username.length < 1 || username.length > 30 ||  username.indexOf(' ') != -1){
                            alert("Username is required\n-should not be less than 1 character\n-not greater than 30 characters\n-It may also not contain spaces");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(password.length < 7 || password.indexOf(' ') !=  -1 ){
                            alert("Password should not be empty\n-should at least be 7 characters");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(retypepassword != password){
                            alert("re-type password should be the same as the password!");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(emailaddress == "" || emailaddress.search(emailRegEx) == -1){
                            alert("Email Address is required and should be a valid email address");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(secondaryemailaddress != emailaddress){
                            alert("Secondary Email address should be the same as the primary email address!");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(secretquestion == ""){
                            alert("Secret Question is required!");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(secretanswer == ""){
                            alert("Secret Answer is required!");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(reffcode == ""){
                            alert("Reference Code is required!");
                            return false;
                          }
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                   }
                });
            },
            "Log in": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $('div#loginpopup').dialog({
                  resizable: false,
                  height: 230,
                  width: 350,
                  modal: true
                })
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: this one `alert("Username is required\n-should not be less than 1 character\n-not greater than 30 characters\n-It may also not contain spaces");` , even if i satisfied that condition for that username field

Comment: make sure your username variable is correctly set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic of validation is fine my guess would be you lose or reset username value at same point or don't set it at all.

Comment: daemn, you're right, the var username and etc.. should be placed inside the dialog function ..thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Just add `autoOpen: false` to your jQuery UI Dialog.

```
$('div#loginpopup').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: 230,
    width: 350,
    modal: true
});
```

Comment: it didn't help..my problem is, the username validation..is there something wrong with it on why the alert box still pops out for that field even if i satisfied the validation for the username field itself ?

Comment: please post youe relevant code and markup as a fiddle i am sure somebody will sort that out soon. right now no one knows what `username` and other vars are.